# CGEventPost fails to deliver keyboard events to another process under Catalina (Mac OSX 10.15)

Tags: macos, core-graphics

We have a little QA helper program (called `keysim`) using `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent` and `CGEventPost` to feed functions keys to the application under test. This did work great until the current Mac OSX version (10.15). Now the program does simply have no effect when the application under test has the focus (and the QA test fails). Any pointers why this happens and how this could be resolved?

Comment: `CGEventPost` has required accessibility access in System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Privacy since macOS 10.14. Does your program have accessibility permission?

Comment: @TheNextman yes, I did that already for `Accessibility` . It didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I did add the `keysim` app under System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Privacy > Developer Tools (The info says : Allow the apps below to run software locally that does not meet the systems security policy).

And this made the function key invocation successful.

IMHO The info is misleading : Our `keysim` program doesn't run software. The info for `Accessibility` says: Allow the apps below to control your computer. So that's why I tried that instead of "Developer Tools".
Never mind: problem solved.